# Invalid Url Parameter when register with bis push service

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-push

When I register with BIS Push from my app it throws an IOException with message `invalid url parameter`  I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: It would help if you posted the Java code that you are using.